# Getting two same volume levels - spotify

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, volume-control

[image]

I've installed Spotify via a normal `.deb` file. I haven't restarted the application nor had a crash since the last boot.

My uptime: `up 3 hours, 41 minutes`

**PS** I've seen the same sometimes in Skype as well.